# NSManagedObjectContext - FetchRequest Deadlock

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, deadlock

**UPDATE NOTE**: I'm using [Big Nerd Ranch CoreDataStack](https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack) if you guys are wondering.

I have been struggling with this specific issue for a while now. Basically I'm trying to fetch contacts from the CNContactStore and fetch ContactDetails (NSManagedObject) in a custom NSOperation.

Right now I'm trying to run the whole procedure on Unit Testing for now. So far this is how my code looks like.

**The Unit Test**

```
func testThatLoaderOperationWorks()
{   
    var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack?   

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    CoreDataStack.constructSQLiteStack(withModelName: "DataModel") { result in
        switch result
        {
        case .Success(let stack):
            coreDataStack = stack
        case .Failure(let error):
            coreDataStack = nil
            print (error)
        }


        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)


    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    let loaderOperation = LoaderOperation.init(withWorkerContext: (coreDataStack?.newChildContext())!, andContactStore: contactStore)
    loaderOperation.completionBlock = {
        XCTAssert(true)
    }

    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    operationQueue.addOperation(loaderOperation)
    loaderOperation.waitUntilFinished()
}
```

**Operation Subclass**

```
override func main()
{       
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey]


    var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
    do
    {
        allContainers = try contactStore.containersMatchingPredicate(nil)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error fetching containers")
    }

    var contactList: [CNContact] = []


    for container in allContainers
    {
        let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier(container.identifier)

        do
        {
            let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
            contactList.appendContentsOf(containerResults)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Error fetching results for container")
        }
    }

    self.workerContext.performBlockAndWait
    {           
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ContactDetails")
        do
        {
            let list = try self.workerContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            print("The List: \(list)")
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Technically what I'm trying to achieve is be able to fetch contacts and cross reference them with the data that I fetch from the CoreData. But the deadlock happens when I run the executeFetchRequest. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Very simple really. This main cause reason is that I was trying to have the test method wait with `waitUntilFinished()` until the operation ends and in the operation itself I was trying to have it forcefully wait with `performBlockAndWait()` thus causing a deadlock.

Remove `waitUntilFinished()` and replace `performBlockAndWait()` with `performBlock()`.

Also in order to do a unit testing with asynchronous code you have to `expectationWithDescription("description")`.

Basically your unit test method should looks like this

```
    let asyncExpectation = expectationWithDescription("longRunningFunction")

    .... some stuff here ....


    let loaderOperation = LoaderOperation.init(withWorkerContext: (coreDataStack?.newChildContext())!, andContactStore: contactStore)
    loaderOperation.completionBlock = {
        asyncExpectation.fulfill()
    }

    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    operationQueue.addOperation(loaderOperation)


    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10) { (error) in
        XCTAssertNil(error, "Something went wrong")
        XCTAssert(true)
    }
```